# constant string expression required ! Error

Tags: java

```
class Restaurant { 
    static float Price;
    static int quantity;
    static float amount;

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String order;

        switch(order) {
            case Starter:
                quantity = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Do you want to add more item.");
                Price = 2500;
                amount = Price * quantity;
                System.out.println(amount);
                break;
            case Main_Meal:
                quantity = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Do you want to add more item ?");
                Price = 2000;
                amount = Price * quantity;
                System.out.println(amount);
            default:
                System.out.println("No order");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll usually get better answers, more quickly (and fewer down votes) if you include the full error message in the question, including which line the error was on. You'll also want to format the code (thanks for including it by the way, that's important) so it's readable. You can do that by indenting all of the code by four spaces (like how Jacob G. edited it). That will allow you to indent the code and make it much easier for people to find the problem.

Comment: `order` Is never set you need a line `order = ...`, same for `Starter` and `Main_Meal`

Comment: But what if I don't want to initialize the order variable and want the user to input the value by himself during the program execution.

Answer (score 3):

`case Starter:` is not a valid switch statement expression. A string literal in switch "case" should be quoted:

```
switch (order) {
  case "Starter":
```

This is described in the [The switch Statement docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

Comment: Sir, thanks for the solution. But I want to know one more thing how could we input value of order variable without initializing when we declare it . Therefore, asking the user to choose from the order.

Comment: You must initialize variable before accessing it, but it doesn't have to be in the same line. You could do `String order; order = scanner.nextLine(); switch (order) ...`